# LDAP login works via terminal, but doesn't work via GUI

Tags: linux, apache, directory, ldap, xubuntu

Please if you could give me some advice of what I'm doing wrong you would make me very happy. I've been struggling with this with no luck and I'm kinda desperate.

- I've got a virtual machine with an LDAP Server installed on Windows Xp. It's Apache Directory Studio.
- Then I've got another virtual machine with Xubuntu on it. I want it to authenticate to Apache Directory Studio.
- The two machines can see each other and do ping correctly.

**Server part (Windows XP with Apache Directory Studio LDAP Server):**

- The server is working great, I did a domain on it dc=mydomain,dc=com with two ou's on it, ou=People and ou=Groups.
- Did some posixAccounts and some posixGroup. Chose high uid numbers (2000 onwards) to avoid conflict.
- All ok on server side.

**Client part (Xubuntu):**

- Entered as root.
- Did:

  apt-get install libnss-ldap
- Configured ip of my LDAP server (checked it, it's "pingable").

[image: LDAP server ip]

- Then entered my domain, for example: dc=mydomain,dc=com.
- Then chose the LDAP version my server is running:

[image: LDAP version]

- Then chose *"yes"* to *"make local root database admin"*.
- Chose *"no"* to *"does the LDAP database require login?"*.
- Then chose the login of the admin of the LDAP Server and it's password. This is 100% confirmed to be true and the actual login, checked it in Apache Directory Studio and verified it many times.

[image: Root]

- Set the password encryption system to "clear".
- Ok, I know that Apache Directory Studio is listening 10389 instead of 389, so I go to /etc/ldap.conf and change manually the port from 389 to 10389 (389 is the default and the GUI doesn't let change you).
- Then IT WORKS, but only via terminal, if I do

  su testuser

It works, because I got that user ONLY in LDAP server, when I test with other users it doesn't work. The same goes for getent passwd testuser.

- Then I want to do graphical login, I close the session, enter credentials and it doesn't work. It works in the terminal, but with GUI don't, oh God, WHY?
- PS: Did apt-get install nscd (as worked for someone) but didn't work out for me.
- PS2: Thanks in advance for your time and patience, and for considering this question (it is not strict programming question).
- PS3: I created the /home/testuser directory, it's not failing because of this, because it still fails to login to LDAP via GUI (but works via terminal).

Comment: are you able to authenticate testuser on terminal/console with password?

Comment: In console yes, in GDM no. That users only exists in LDAP, i'm sure of that.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is GDM Try following

Automatically create home folders

Just edit `/etc/pam.d/common-session` by hand and adding the following line before any `pam_ldap` and `pam_krb5` settings:

```
session required        pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0022 skel=/etc/skel
```

make sure you have gdm entry in `/etc/security/group.conf`

and following line in `/etc/pam.d/gdm`

```
auth optional pam_group.so
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, I'm sorry for the late. I followed your instructions but it didn't work. What I should write in /etc/security/group.conf? I can't find any reference of gdm in that file. More, the file /etc/pam.d/gdm doesn't exist, it's blank. I write the text you say me but GDM keeps not working. Any additional clue? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Here is a nice reference of ldap and GDM http://ldots.org/ldap/

Comment: Important: GDM requires TLS encryption to be enable with LDAP,  For security reasons otherwise it wont work.

Answer (score 2):

For users who login using X /etc/pam.d/gdm has to be modified so GDM will use LDAP.
Something like:

```
auth     sufficient     pam_ldap.so
auth     required       pam_nologin.so
auth     required       pam_env.so
auth     required       pam_unix_auth.so

account  sufficient     pam_ldap.so
account  required       pam_unix_acct.so

password required       pam_ldap.so

session  sufficient     pam_ldap.so
session  required       pam_unix_session.so
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to perform a

```
getent passwd
```

Form the command line and display if the users are being returned from the LDAP server.
All the users from the /etc/passwd and the users from LDAP should be displayed.

Comment: Yeah, it displays LDAP users, but GDM keeps not working. Login via su works (to LDAP Users) but login via GDM not works (to LDAP users). Thanks for your time and your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Too late answer but might help others as i got through this.

In the terminal use

```
sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-auth
```

add these lines at the bottom `auth    required    pam_access.so`

and in this file `sudo nano /etc/security/access.conf`

add this line `-:ALL EXCEPT root (admin):ALL EXCEPT LOCAL` at the bottom

For more info: [Authenticate Client Computers Using LDAP](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-authenticate-client-computers-using-ldap-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and none of above answers solved it .This are config done by me on Ubuntu 18.04 and on kali as well

Steps we need to follow are as follows

1. Install libpam-ldap / libnss-ldap
   Ubuntu:

`apt-get install libpam-ldap`

kali Linux:

```
apt-get install libpam-ldap libnss-ldapd
```

2. Configure ldap settings

   `dpkg-reconfigure libpam-ldap`

do all setting as yes and local database creation : yes

```
base : ou-People,dc=sqtk,dc=team

root dn : dc=admin,dc=sqtk,dc=team
```

every option asked should be yes (store database on local yes and specify ldap admin username and password )
for database stuff use admin user only

3. Change /etc/nsswitch.conf to let passwd , group , shadow to use **ldap** and **netgroup** to **nis**

/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd: files ldap
group: files ldap
shadow: files ldap
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup: nis
```

NOTE : Change netgroup to nis(network information system) this signifies that the groups are also 
fetched from netgroup from nis so in below step we do group mapping (My assumption , dont question it, it worked)

Now we can verify whether we can connect to ldap server by using below command

```
ldapsearch -x -W -D 'cn=ldaptest,ou=People,dc=sqtk,dc=team' -b "" -s base
```

3.We need to set to create a  home dir as soon as users logs in this is achieved by using **pam_mkhomedir.so** (verify if it is present by doing a find find / -name pam_mkhomedir.so if not present then install it should be present by default)

3.1 Currently when we run command

```
pam-auth-config
```

we dont see a option for mkhomedir (make home directory which is neccessary as user logs in)
3.2 to get this option we need to create a file  /usr/share/pam-configs/mkhomedir if not present with following content

content :

```
Name: activate mkhomedir
Default: yes
Priority: 900
Session-Type: Additional
Session:
        required                        pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0022 skel=/etc/skel
```

3.3 Now if we run command

```
pam-auth-config
```

we see option for **mkhomedir** so we need to select it as well (we select option by using a space on keyboard )
3.4 To verify whether mkhomedir is set we can `cat /etc/pam.d/common-session` file and see a entry as below (dont edit the file manually try and use pam-auth-update only ) It will have a entry as below

```
session required        pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0022 skel=/etc/skel
```

4. ldap domain to group mapping

4.1 we need to do a domain mapping with the ldap group tehnical this mapping is nothing but we mapping ldap group name to group id of ldap in local .

I faced a issue where in i used to get the group id i.e > 500 of ldap group on local system but somehow system was not able to fetch the group name for the given id so i did below config

4.2 To assign local groups to a domain (ldap) user do the following edit `/etc/security/group.conf` and add something like the following to it

```
*;*;*;Al0000-2400;audio,cdrom,dialout,floppy
```

4.3 In order to get the pam_group module working you could create a file like `/usr/share/pam-configs/my_groups`:

```
Name: activate /etc/security/group.conf
Default: yes
Priority: 900
Auth-Type: Primary
Auth:
        required                        pam_group.so use_first_pass
```

Now we activate it by running

```
pam-auth-update
```

This roughly equals editing `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` by hand and adding the following line before any pam_ldap and pam_krb5 settings:

```
auth    required     pam_group.so use_first_pass
```

**IMPORTANT # You should now have local groups showing up for users logging in via gdm and ssh and can**
**# verify this by  # executing id or groups.**

4.4 Now we need to verify whether we get just the group name and id use below command

```
getent group
```

If command doent work or display verify whether you can connect to ldap server

you can also verify whether we can fetch user from ldap by firing below command

```
getent passwd

id <username in ldap>
```

Again if anyone of the above commands doesnt perform as accepted then verify whether we can connect to ldap successfully use below command

```
ldapsearch -x -W -D 'cn=bumbum,ou=People,dc=sqtk,dc=team' -b "" -s base
-W == prompt for password
-D == User to validate
```

5. Ldap Group to be given sudo access 
   Give sudo access to the group that are present on ldap and are make sure user are part of the same group with whom you are login

   visudo
   % ALL=(ALL) ALL

if group name is ldaptest then below line needs to be  added

```
%ldaptest ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

You should be able to login from desktop as well as terminal

(Note : for above things to works install **libnss-ldapd** package for **kali Linux** only then it works )